# Quartz RMI remote server returning invalid hostname

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, rmi

I have 2 processes on separate servers. One is running the Quartz scheduler and I want to connect to it from the other to manage triggers.

On the scheduler server the config is:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.createRegistry = always
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost = localhost
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort = 1099
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.serverPort = 1100
```

On the remote server the config is:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost = ip-172-16-5-11.eu-west-1.compute.internal
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort = 1099
```

When I try and connect to the remote scheduler I get the following error in the log:

```
ERROR [2016-07-28 09:10:23,017] xxxx: Error communicating with remote scheduler.
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
! ... 83 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: log-emea-1; nested exception is:
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Although this host is a host on our network I have no idea why it is being returned by the remote registry.

There are no connectivity issues. If I run tcpdump on the remote machine I can see it connecting to the scheduler. It's just that the scheduler is returning this invalid host:

```
09:19:02.047589 IP 172.16.5.11.1099 > 172.16.0.81.54065: Flags [P.], seq 19:235, ack 105, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 1231389006 ecr 562121102], length 216
E.....@.@..........Q.K.1}.Z... ......c.....
Ie.N!.I.Q....w..9.e2...V0.|...sr.$org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler_Stub...........pxr..java.rmi.server.RemoteStub......e....pxr..java.rmi.server.RemoteObject.a...a3....pxpw3.
UnicastRef.
log-emea-1...L/8.   .a.69.e2...V0.|....x
```

Where is the Quartz RMI registry getting this hostname from? There are no clues in the hosts file or DNS. It appears to be random.

Answer (score 1):

You could start your scheduler with the following JVM-Flag

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=...
```

(see [RMI-FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain) or [Why does java rmi keep connecting to 127.0.1.1. When ip is 192.168.X.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478649/why-does-java-rmi-keep-connecting-to-127-0-1-1-when-ip-is-192-168-x-x))

Answer (score 0):

I tried the JVM flag but that made no difference however it did lead me to a solution. I set the property in code and that fixed the problem.

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "quartz");
```

Comment: But that is the same like `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=quartz`

Comment: Yes, in theory they should be the same but in practice it appears not.

Comment: You could validate that with `System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname")` . Just in case you want ensure that it was not an typo or something else ;)